# Use custom function in Proxy URL in Schema config

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When I define a base class for models I can configure schema with default proxy config:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Base', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty : 'ID',

    schema : {
        namespace : 'App.model',
        proxy     : {
            type : 'rest',

            url : '{prefix}/{entityName:lowercase}'
        }
    }
});
```

Where :lowercase in `url` is a Ext.util.Format function.

How can I use my custom function here or configure it on construct so that I can get entityName as a variable and transform it (for example add dashes between words)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a model constructor, like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Base', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty : 'ID',

    constructor: function(config) {
        // Check your config properly
        if(config) {
            // Your function to build url
            var buildUrl = function (data) {
                // Do stuff
            }

            Ext.apply(this, {
                schema : {
                    namespace : 'App.model',
                    proxy     : {
                        type : 'rest',
                        url : buildUrl(config)
                    }                        
                }
            });
        }

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Create new instance of `App.model.Base` like this:

```
Ext.create('App.model.Base', {
    // Your url config
    prefix: ...,
    entityName: ...,
    ...
});
```